# Prove that if $p\mid(aq)^2$ and $(a,p) = 1$ then $p = q$ where $p,q$ are primes.

Tags: number-theory

There is a theorem that if $p\mid aq$ and $(p,a) = 1$ then $p|q$ but I don't know how to use this theorem to solve the problem.

Comment: I think you mean to say that $p\mid q$ in your title, not $p=q$.

Comment: Also is $p$ assumed to be prime..? You need to add all details.

Comment: I think yes, as he mentioned a theorem which works for a prime $p$.

Comment: The wording of the title is quite poor imo. It could be understood as "if $p$ and $q$ are primes such as ... then ..." or "if $p$ and $q$ are integers such as ... then ... and $p$ and $q$ are primes." At first I read the latter, although the OP meant the former (I think).

Answer (score 2):

By the theorem you quoted, since $p$ divides $(a)(aq^2)$, and $p$ and $a$ are relatively prime, it follows that $p$ divides $aq^2$.

By the same theorem, we then conclude that $p$ divides $q^2$.

By the same theorem, if $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime, it follows that $p$ divides $q$, which is impossible.

So $p$ and $q$ are not relatively prime. It follows that $p=q$.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** $p|n\iff p=\gcd(n,p)$.

Now $\gcd(a,p)=1\Rightarrow \gcd(a^2,p)=1$ **(why?)**

Given $p|a^2q^2$, thus by the theorem you stated $p|q^2\Rightarrow p|q$ **(why?)**

Now, $p$ and $q$ are both primes and $p|q$, what can you conclude?

Answer (score 1):

$p \mid (aq)^2 \implies p\mid aq \implies p \mid q$

Comment: Simplicity at its best! +1